# python sqlite query that only updates values if the variables used are not NULL

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update

My sqlite query is updating columns with the empty variables that are being passed in instead of ignoring the empty variables and keeping the current value in the column.

My program askes the user to input info into each of those variables or leave blank if that column does not need to be changed. Variables left blank need to be ignored and the current value in the column needs to kept. This is my way of letting the user update multiple columns at once instead of only updating one at a time and then having to start over.

I am using python 3 and sqlite3.

Here is the code chunk that I tried running.

```
                c.execute('''UPDATE filaments SET brand= CASE WHEN ? IS NOT NULL THEN ? ELSE brand END, 
                            material= CASE WHEN ? IS NOT NULL THEN ? ELSE material END, 
                            color= CASE WHEN ? IS NOT NULL THEN ? ELSE color END, 
                            spools= CASE WHEN ? IS NOT NULL THEN ? ELSE spools END,
                            size= CASE WHEN ? IS NOT NULL THEN ? ELSE size END,
                            weight= CASE WHEN ? IS NOT NULL THEN ? ELSE weight END,
                            price= CASE WHEN ? IS NOT NULL THEN ? ELSE price END 
                            WHERE id = ?''', (b,b,m,m,co,co,sc,sc,ss,ss,sw,sw,p,p,slct))
                conn.commit()
                print("Process complete!")
```

Comment: What is exactly the issue you're having?

Comment: The current query is updating columns with the null values instead of ignoring them and keeping the current values in the columns.

Comment: Are you sure that the parameters are None and not just an empty string?

Comment: The variables are set to None at the beginning to clear them of any potential entries. Then the program asks for the input. Is python updating the None value to an empty string after receiving nothing as an input?

Comment: Most likely. If the user just presses enter you will get an empty string.

Comment: You can log the value of the parameters to the query so you know exactly what you're passing to the query

Comment: You were right. The variables were being set as empty strings. I added "if len(b) < 1: b = None" and it worked for b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to have the answer here, make sure that you're passing None instead of empty strings.

Also it would be much cleaner if instead of the case statement you use COALESCE.

size = COALESCE(?, size)

This way you reduce the parameters to the query in half as you specify one column only once.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is my first time using python and this was driving me crazy. Turned out I was looking at the wrong piece of code all along. I will give coalesce a shot and see how it goes. I am always looking for ways to improve.